How to swap out a child object with another, preserving the parent inverse matrix?
I have a blend file which links an object from another file (e.g. a pistol). This object is part of a larger model (a person, who is holding this pistol). If I update the linked object , in the linked file, eg add child objects to it, the copy in my main blend file does not update. So, I need to replace the existing linked child object with a new copy of this linked child object. But, there are animations on everything, so I need to preserve the Parent Inverse Matrix. How to do this?

Spent a while searching around for this. In the end, the most straightforward approach appears to be to use the python console. Basically:

with the current linked object selected, paste the following into the python console:

    obj = bpy.context.object
    pim = obj.matrix_parent_inverse
    s = 'pim = Matrix(('
    for j in range(4):
        s += '('
        for i in range(4):
            if i > 0:
                s += ','
            s += str(pim[j][i])
        s += '),'
    s += '))'
    print(s)


add the new linked object, parent it to the existing parent, using any parenting option, since you'll replcae the PIM in step 3 anyway.

The code above printed out a python command. With the new linked object selected, first run:


obj = bpy.context.object

... then run the python script from earlier. It will look something like:
obj.matrix_parent_inverse = Matrix(((0.16599735617637634,-0.0,0.0,-1.2911996841430664),(-0.0,1.0,-0.0,-6.202362537384033),(0.0,-0.0,1.0,0.36063331365585327),(-0.0,0.0,-0.0,1.0),))

Hopefully, your new linked object copy will pop into the right place :)
(If you're using animations, simply moving the timeline will handle the locatino, rotation, and scale, but if you want to copy those, you can use a similar approach:
loc = obj.location
s = f'loc = Vector(({loc.x}, {loc.y}, {loc.z}))'
print(s)

rot =obj.rotation_euler
s = f'rot = Euler(({rot.x}, {rot.y}, {rot.z}), "XYZ")'
print(s)

scale = obj.scale
s = f'scale = Vector(({scale.x}, {scale.y}, {scale.z}))'
print(s)

